# i3-6100U CPU not compatible to run on Kali Linux 2018.4 32-bit version on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, bios, virtualization, kali-linux

32-bit Ubuntu Oracle Virtualbox and 32-bit Kali Linux version 2018.4 isn't working.

All are the newest versions.

My BIOS is locked so i can't turn on virtualization.

If going into the BIOS turning on virtualization is the fix then how do i get into the / how do i reset the password BIOS without opening the computer taking out the battery holding the battery etc.

If that's the only way then i'll open the computer at home, please tell me if theres any other way

I have PAE/NX on which results in me getting a blackscreen when pressing on graphical install, 
when i disable PAE. Then a text show's up saying that the Kernel needs the following PAE to boot up which results with me getting a black screen enabling PAE.

Any other errors that you think is making Kali Linux version 2018.4 not work for me, then tell me down below.

Here's a bunch of pictures with all of my settings

[When i'm on the first meny and press graphical install then = blackscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3vXT.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ7ke.png)

[VM Settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkepr.png)

[VM Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D53R.png)

[PC Version / Bios / CPU etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6khV7.png)

[With Pae / NX off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSZiA.png)

[Here are some of my settings in VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWBs1.png)

Comment: The fact you enabled Hyper-V means VT-x has to be enabled.  You cannot enable VT-x support within VirtualBox while Hyper-V is enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound what should i put it on? none, default, legacy, minimal, Hyper-V or KBM?

Comment: Screenshots without a translation to English make it very difficult to formulate an answer to your question.

Comment: @safaxd - Please be specific, when you say “it”, what exactly is “it”.  Please edit your question to provide the necessary information to answer your question.  If you have Hyper-V installed and enabled, is there a reason, your using VirtualBox instead of Hyper-V to run Kali?

Comment: @Ramhound sorry for being so bad at explaining things, I have searched on the internet on this for hours and right now i'm really trying my best to explain. I replaced all the it's with what i was talking about.

Comment: I think you need to enable "Intel Virtualization Technology" from BIOS. Reset your BIOS with the vendor's utility and enable it.

Comment: @Overmind - It’s already enabled since Hyper-V is installed on the system

Comment: @Overmind the problem here is that my BIOS is locked, also, I will check and see if it is enabled now when my Hyper-V ins enabled. Kali Linux still isn't working.

Comment: Since you've already got Hyper-V enabled, why not just use that?  Here's info for installing Kali in Hyper-V: https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/kali-linux-client-hyper-v/